# How do you send a Slack Notification from a console command in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

It's very easy to send a Slack notification when a new record is created but how do you do it within an Artisan::command?

Kernel.php

```
$schedule->command('vacationReminder')->daily()->at('07:00');
```

console.php

```
Artisan::command('vacationReminder', function () {
    $this->notify(new VacationReminder());
})->purpose('Remind employees who is on vacation');
```

I know the above is wrong but what do I need to fire off the Slack notification from console.php?  When I send from a model, for example, I need to import

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\VacationReminder;
```

and have the function

```
public function routeNotificationForSlack($notification)
    {
        return env('SLACK_NOTIFICATION_WEBHOOK');
    }
```

How do these come into play when trying to send a notification from console.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to use a config file to access ENV variables (instead of using `env()` directly). Create a config file `config/notifications.php` with the following code:

```
<?php

return [
    'slack' => env('SLACK_NOTIFICATION_WEBHOOK')
];
```

You can later access the config variable using `config('notifications.slack')`. Then in your `console.php` you use the Notification facade and your VacationReminder notification by adding

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use App\Notifications\VacationReminder;
```

at the top. Finally, create your command:

```
Artisan::command('vacationReminder', function () {
    Notification::route('slack', config('notifications.slack'))
        ->notify(new VacationReminder());
})->describe('Remind employees who is on vacation');
```

This uses [On-Demand Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications#on-demand-notifications) so you don't need to have a model with the `Notifiable` trait.